# Correct use of when/as ... was/has been

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure if this sentence is correct.

(Terms written as `SpreadFilter` are technical terms so don't bother with them.)

> I fixed an error that caused the `SpreadFilter` to `throw a NullPointerException` when the filter was reset.

I'm unsure wheter it is

*... when the filter was reset.*

*... as the filter was reset.*

*... when the filter has been reset.*

*... as the filter has been reset.*

What I want to say is:

> There is a filter and everytime a user clicked the reset button, the filter `throw a NullPointerException`. This is now fixed.

Comment: Your first example is fine! :)

Comment: I agree that your first example is fine as is, but you might consider replacing "when" with either "whenever", "each time", or "every time" (two words) to make it clearer that this was happening every time and not just once or sporadically. Also (and this involves one of the "technical terms" so maybe 'tech terms rule supreme over verb tenses'), "throw" in your last sentence should be in either the past tense: "threw," or the conditional: "would throw.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first sentence is correct:

> I fixed an error that caused the SpreadFilter to throw a NullPointerException when the filter was reset.

Disregard the beginning of the sentence and look at this part:

> ... an error caused the SpreadFilter to throw a NullPointerException when the filter was reset.

Try putting the prepositional phrase in the front, and it should be easier to tell which option is the best. The sentence becomes the following:

> When the filter was reset, an error caused the SpreadFilter to throw a NullPointerException.

If you use one of the other phrases you suggested, it seems awkward and out of place:

> As the filter has been reset, an error caused the SpreadFilter to throw a NullPointerException.